# How do I delete UITableview cells by tapping a UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to delete all the UITableviewCells in my Tableview by tapping a button

**UITableView DataSource Methods**

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return UserList.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FriendAddCell" , for: indexPath) as! AddFriendLTableViewCell
    cell.lb_Email.text = UserList[indexPath.row].userEmail
    let imageUrl = URL(string: UserList[indexPath.row].imageUrl)
    cell.img_Avatar.loadImageUrl(url: imageUrl!)

    return cell
}
```

**My Button Function**

```
@IBAction func btn_NewAddUser(_ sender: Any) {
    UserList.removeAll()
    table_SearchFirends.reloadData()
}
```

the cells I tried to delete still exist when I add a new cell

How can I delete all the cells by pressing the button?

How can I make the tableView as if there were no rows created?

Answer (score 1):

How I can understand your problem that you see empty lines with separator lines on bottom.

Make this for remove extra lines:

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

And some advise - use camelCase style in Swift.

Comment: thank you for your advice, but my problem is that there are 10 lines in my list as an example, I added, how can I delete them all with the button

Comment: It's like that your collection is not empty and keep some data.

try this code

tableView.dataSource = nil
tableView.reloadData()